# How can I Select from a table where 3 out of 4 columns have identical values?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find potential duplicate records. For example. 
Where

- FirstName = FirstName
- LastName = LastName
- DOB = DOB
- Street Address = Street Address

So FirstName, LastName, and DOB are all the same. Or FirstName, LastName, and StreetAddress. Or LastName, DOB, and SteetAddress. And so on......

My client wants the records where 3 out of the 4 values are the same. 
Can this be done in MySql? Or do I need to do some processing in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Just use SELECT DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first, last, dob, street
FROM Your_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

customer(id, firstname, dob)

To retrieve the customer ids that have same firstname:

```
select id
from customer
where firstname in (select firstname
             from customer
             group by firstname
             having count(*)>1);
```

Or else you'll have to join the table upon itself:

```
select a.id
from customer a, customer b
where (a.firstname=b.firstname and a.lastname=b.lastname and a.dob=b.dob) or 
        (a.firstname=b.firstname and a.lastname=b.lastname and a.address=b.address) or
        (a.firstname=b.firstname and a.dob=b.dob and a.address=b.address) or
        (a.lastname=b.lastname and a.dob=b.dob and a.address=b.address);
```

Comment: That only gives me FirstNames that are a match. I need 3 out of 4 that match

Answer (score 0):

first off add an index:

```
alter table whatever add key(DOB,LastName,FirstName,StreetAddress);
```

then to see if you the duplicate rows across three of the fields - in this case DOB, FN and LN:

```
select DOB,LastName,FirstName,StreetAddress from whatever t1 
inner join (
 select DOB,LastName,FirstName,StreetAddress from whatever 
group by DOB,LastName,FirstName,StreetAddress ) as t2 
on t1.DOB=t2.DOB 
and t1.LastName=t2.LastName
and t1.FirstName=t2.FirstName
where t1.StreetAddress != t2.StreetAddress;
```

to look for other combinations, change thefields you join on and the fields in the where clause..